# Zoho Deluge code debugging: How do I correct the below code in Zoho deluge

Tags: zoho, zoho-deluge

// create a new form named Acknowledgement_Form

Acknowledgement_Form = create form('Acknowledgement_Form');

//Adding fields to the new form

formB = Acknowledgement_Form;

formB.add(field1: input.Team_Lead,field2: input.confirmation );

I want to use the above to create a new form on success of form A. I wrote the above code but I keep getting error. I will appreciate if anyone could help me out

I was expecting the above to add action to the workflow of form A but i keep getting error message.